# LINQ to SQL - need downloading sqlserver 2008 to a local mdf file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

i have a sql server that i use and i am trying to code up a solution using LINQ to SQl in visual studio.

is there a way i can:

download the database from my server to my local desktop and have it as a mdf file so i can bring it into the app_data folder and it use this for LINQ to SQL code generation.

also, please let me know if there is a better way to achieve what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you want to do is create your Linq to SQL classes? If so, just connect to your SQL server and generate them from there -- no need for a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you cannot. Better go to the server, detach the mdf, copy it and attach the mdf again, or do a backup/restore.

I think that you might have to change your post title to get any helpful answer.